# Using a boundary file from a shape file in a R2BayesX model

Tags: r

Greetings I am using a South African shapefile which I converted to a boundary map object to using in R2BayesX linking it to districts variable for spatial structured (correlated) effect using Markov Random Field prior but I get an error.

This is my code:

```
 Code:
    library("R2BayesX")
    shpname <- file.path(find.package("R2BayesX"), "examples", "SA")
    sa_map <- shp2bnd(shpname = shpname, regionnames = "ID_2")
    plot(sa_map)
    dat <- read.csv("Adult.csv",header = T,sep=",")
    attach(dat)
    ctr <- bayesx.control(model.name = "OrdRes",outfile = "C:/OrdRes",family 
    ="cumlogit",method = "REML")
    m1 <- health ~ sx(districts,bs="mrf",map=sa_map)
    sm <- bayesx(m1,data = dat,control = ctr)

    I get an error:

    bayesx_logfile(sm)
    NOTE: created directory C:\OrdRes11\temp
    NOTE: created directory C:\OrdRes11\output
    logopen using C:/OrdRes11/OrdRes.input.prg.log
    remlreg b
    map saIi11iImap
    saIi11iImap.infile using C:/OrdRes11/saIi11iImap.bnd
    NOTE: 52 regions read from file C:/OrdRes11/saIi11iImap.bnd
    dataset d
    d.infile using C:/OrdRes11/OrdRes.data.raw
    NOTE: 3 variables with 16449 observations read from file
    C:/OrdRes11/OrdRes.data.raw

    b.outfile = C:/OrdRes11/OrdRes
    b.regress health = districts(spatial,map=saIi11iImap),
    family=cumlogit eps=1e-05 lowerlim=0.001 maxit=400
    maxchange=1e+06 using d
    *"ERROR: map is disconnected, spatial effect cannot be estimated"*
    logclose
    NOTE: log-file C:/OrdRes11/OrdRes.input.prg.log closed
```

This are the districts levels from the map object:

```
        ->levels(as.factor(samap$DC_MN_C))

        "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "12"  
        "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21"  "22"  "23" 
        "24"  "25"  "26"  "27"  "28"  "29"  "30"  "31"  "32"  "33"  "34"  
        "35"  "36"  "37"  "38"  "39"  "40"  "42"  "43"  "44"  "76"  "81" 
        "82"  "83"  "84"  "88"  "171" "275" "572" "773" "774"
```

And this are the district levels from my data:

```
        ->levels(as.factor(district2001_01))

        "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "12"  
        "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21"  "22"  "23" 
        "24"  "25"  "26"  "27"  "28"  "29"  "30"  "31"  "32"  "33"  "34"  
        "35"  "36"  "37"  "38"  "39"  "40"  "42"  "43"  "44"  "76"  "81" 
        "82"  "83"  "84"  "88"  "171" "275" "572" "773" "774"
```

Which is really why I don't under why I get an error. Please kindly assist with this issue.
This are variables of the shapefile

```
 ->cbind(samap$DC_MDB_C,samap$DC_NAME,samap$DC_MN_C,
 samap$ORGUNIT,samap$DISTRICT,samap$OUTYPE,samap$OUAUTHOR)
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
  [1,]    1   13  171   50   10    2   13
  [2,]    2   24   81   43   24    1   24
  [3,]    3   26   82   16   26    1   26
  [4,]    4   36   83   38   36    1   36
  [5,]    5    4   84   34    4    1    4
  [6,]    6   51   88   18   51    1   51
  [7,]    7   50    1   53   50    1   50
  [8,]    8    8   10    3    9    1    8
  [9,]    9    3   12    2    3    1    3
  [10,]   10   12   13    4    8    1   12
  [11,]   11   42   14    7   42    1   42
  [12,]   12   33   15    6   33    1   33
  [13,]   13   52   16   12   52    1   52
  [14,]   14   28   17    9   28    1   28
  [15,]   15   25   18    8   25    1   25
  [16,]   16   40   19   11   40    1   40
  [17,]   17    6    2   48    6    1    6
  [18,]   18   32   20   10   29    1   32
  [19,]   19   41   21   23   41    1   41
  [20,]   20   43   22   24   43    1   43
  [21,]   21   46   23   27   46    1   46
  [22,]   22   45   24   26   45    1   45
  [23,]   23    2   25   19    2    1    2
  [24,]   24   53   26   29   53    1   53
  [25,]   25   44   27   25   44    1   44
  [26,]   26   47   28   28   47    1   47
  [27,]   27   22   29   21   22    1   22
  [28,]   28   34    3   52   34    1   34
  [29,]   29   21   30   36   21    1   21
  [30,]   30   31   31   37   32    1   31
  [31,]   31   17   32   35   17    1   17
  [32,]   32   27   33   31   27    1   27
  [33,]   33   48   34   32   48    1   48
  [34,]   34    9   35   30   11    1    9
  [35,]   35   49   36   33   49    1   49
  [36,]   36    5   37   44    5    1    5
  [37,]   37   10   38   46   12    1   10
  [38,]   38    7   39   45    7    1    7
  [39,]   39   16    4   51   16    1   16
  [40,]   40   39   40   47   39    1   39
  [41,]   41   35   42   15   35    1   35
  [42,]   42   37   43   22   37    1   37
  [43,]   43    1   44    1    1    1    1
  [44,]   44   11    5   49   13    1   11
  [45,]   45   29    6   40   31    1   29
  [46,]   46   23    7   39   23    1   23
  [47,]   47   38    8   41   38    1   38
  [48,]   48   20    9   42   20    1   20
  [49,]   49   19  572   20   19    2   19
  [50,]   50   18  773   14   18    2   18
  [51,]   51   14  774   13   14    2   14
  [52,]   52   30  275    5   30    2   30
  [53,]   53   15   76   17   15    2   15
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the error that you get.

Comment: library("R2BayesX")
    shpname <- file.path(find.package("R2BayesX"), "examples", "SA")
    sa_map <- shp2bnd(shpname = shpname, regionnames = "ID_2")
    plot(sa_map) , From this map object samap, i run a code fitting a model:                        ctr <- bayesx.control(model.name = "OrdRes",outfile = "C:/OrdRes",family 
    ="cumlogit",method = "REML")
    m1 <- health ~ sx(districts,bs="mrf",map=sa_map)
    sm <- bayesx(m1,data = dat,control = ctr)

Comment: From this map object samap, i run a code fitting a model:                                                                                                       ctr <- bayesx.control(model.name = "OrdRes",outfile = "C:/OrdRes",family 
    ="cumlogit",method = "REML")
    m1 <- health ~ sx(districts,bs="mrf",map=sa_map)
    sm <- bayesx(m1,data = dat,control = ctr), the Error is for the samap   ERROR: map is disconnected, spatial effect cannot be estimated

Answer (score 0):

This question usually happens when you have some regions (e.g., islands) out of the main areas of a map. The MRF in the structured additive regression (STAR) model has a strict condition that all areas should have at least one neighbor, which is determined by adjacent boundaries of each area when using a shapefile. If some of your areas have no neighbors, you'll get the error message:

ERROR: map is disconnected, spatial effect cannot be estimated

There are two solutions:

1. Manually deleting those areas with no neighbor in the shapefile. This can be done in GIS software, such as ArcGIS or QGIS.
2. Intentionally adding neighbors in those areas with no neighbors. This can only work on the .gra file, so you need to convert your shapefile or boundary file into a .gra file. Then, you can take a look at the map to see which areas are close but not adjacent to those areas with no neighbors, then you can use the function add.neighbor() to add neighbors in the .gra file.

After adding neighbors, you can use get.neighbor() function to make sure whether all areas have neighbors. If so, then your STAR model may work. Why do I say it may work? Because there are a lot of convergence issues in the STAR model. It is not guaranteed that your model will be estimable even there is no problem in the map data.

The STAR model is a really convenient approach to do spatial analysis, while the software "BayesX" has a lot of issues with no further explanations in its manual. Its R package 'R2BayesX" is not an independent package to run the STAR model, but replies on a pre-installed BayesX software in your computer. Thus, you can suppose that the R2BayesX package is just a translater to translate your R codes into BayesX codes, which are eventually sent to the BayesX software to fit the model, and return the outputs to R. I spent several years to fight with those error messages in BayesX, and indeed published a lot of papers by using the STAR model. However, I still encounter a lot of unknown crushes in the software. Whether the software will work is full of uncertainty and luck.

I recognize that you posted the question one year ago, so my answer may not be in time to deal with your problem. However, I still hope that my answer can help other users who  encounter the same problem when using the package.